# JQuery и размер окна браузера

Tags: jquery, браузер

Добрый вечер, как заставить сценарий работать при уже изначально измененном окне браузера?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).resize(function() {
                if ($(window).width() <= '995'){
           $('#shelf').show(10)
            return this;}
         else   {
              $('#shelf').hide(10)
            }

    });
});
```

При изменении окна все работает, но когда окно изначально 800px - нет ...

Comment: А зачем это - **return this;**?

Comment: Пардон я ступил, return this - не нужен, все что было нужно убрать display: none; с этого id в css

Comment: Ну как? Окно уже 800px или ещё нет?

Comment: "как сценарий работать" - моя твоя не понимать.

Comment: неа, не помог display: block; так как первоначально, на полном размере окна, #shelf должен быть не виден

Comment: А как понимать "изначально измененном"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[[@Kp Houseoff](/users/11859/kp-houseoff)](/users/11859/kp-houseoff), у вас изменения происходят только по событию **.resize()**. Если вам надо высчитывать при загрузке, то и ставьте именно это событи, а именно **.load()**:

```
function windowSize(){
    if ($(window).width() <= '995'){
        $('#shelf').show(10);
    } else {
        $('#shelf').hide(10);
    }
}
$(window).load(windowSize); // при загрузке
$(window).resize(windowSize); // при изменении размеров
// или "два-в-одном", вместо двух последних строк:
$(window).on('load resize',windowSize);
```

Comment: Спасибо! все что было (из очков)

Comment: @Kp Houseoff, не нужно нажимать "наградить"! По крайней мере, пока у вас не набралось достаточно баллов. Достаточно нажать "галочку" напротив вопроса и принять ответ, как правильный.

Comment: Ну... Не страшно

Answer (score 0):

Выполнять проверку надо сразу. В вашем коде пока не произошел .resize() - не проверяется условие.